# I would like to be able to let people login/logout on the first page of my grails application

Tags: grails, authentication, indexing, logout

I'd like to have login and logout on the first page of my grails application and have any error messages displayed there. I have an authentication function coded in my User domain along with a logout function. After someone logs in in the authenticate function, I manage to get them back to the main screen by doing a redirect:

```
redirect(uri:"")
```

If I do the same thing with the logout, I get an error when the page is rendered, saying it can't find the user object. Below is the output.

Error 500: Executing action [logout] of controller [com.thornglatch.pingo.UserController] caused exception: No such property: name for class: com.thornglatch.pingo.User Possible solutions: games
Servlet: grails
URI: /Pingo/grails/user/logout.dispatch
Exception Message: No such property: name for class: com.thornglatch.pingo.User Possible solutions: games
Caused by: No such property: name for class: com.thornglatch.pingo.User Possible solutions: games
Class: UserController
At Line: [25]

Here is the stuff it's trying to render, I believe:

```
<div id="menu">
  <nobr>
    <g:if test="${session.user}">
      <b>${session.user?.firstName}&nbsp;${session.user?.lastName}</b> |
        <g:link controller="user" action="logout">Logout</g:link>
    </g:if>
    <g:else>
      <g:link controller="user" action="login">Login</g:link>
    </g:else>
  </nobr>
</div>
```

Thank you for your time and attention.

---

Here's the Authenticate code:

```
def authenticate = {
    println "Authenticate Entered"
    def user = User.findByLoginAndPassword(params.login, params.password)
    println "User = [" + user + "]"
    if (user) {
        session.user = user
        def name = user.firstName ?: user.lastName
        flash.message = "Hello ${user.login}"
        redirect(uri:"")
    } else {
        println "Should be saying sorry"
        flash.message = "Sorry, ${params.login}. Please try again.}"
        redirect(uri:"")
    }
} // authenticate
```

This version works. In the one that didn't, the flash.message line was:

```
flash.message = "Hello ${name}"
```

I can live with this, but would like to know why using name didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look as a functional error, like the problem you've described. In fact the snippet seems okay, it's being invoked correctly.

The problem seems to be that you're attempting to access a property that doesn't exists (`name`) at runtime in the class `com.thornglatch.pingo.User`.

Have a look at `com.thornglatch.pingo.UserController` line 25 and check that the `name` you're accessing has a setter and getter or it is a public field in `com.thornglatch.pingo.User`. Or check that, if it's a variable, the declaration exists.

Remember that Groovy is a dynamic language, thus you have to be careful since member field access checks will happen at runtime.

Comment: I added additional information after re-examining the code with your comments in mind. I have a version that works now, but still have a question, as you can see.

Comment: Well, "name" should work. Have you tried with "def name='Hardcoded Name'"?